# Convert string saved in hex format to its previous form in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, hex

I'm writing program in Python
I have unicode characters based text and it is saved in file in following format:
%D0%9D%D2%B1%D1%80%D1%81%D2%B1%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D3%98%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%88%D2%B1%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2
I want to decode it back into utf8.

so if I have:

```
title = "%D0%9D%D2"
```

How to decode it back to UTF8 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That string appears to be using percent-encoding, which means you first have to unescape it. You could do something like

```
import urllib
s = "%D0%9D%D2%B1%D1%80%D1%81%D2%B1%D0%BB%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD_%D3%98%D0%B1%D1%96%D1%88%D2%B1%D0%BB%D1%8B_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B"
print urllib.unquote(s)
```

Which gives an output of

```
Нұрсұлтан_Әбішұлы_Назарбаев
```

The result of `urllib.unquote` will give you a unicode-escaped string. The Python 3 equivelant is, I think, `urllib.parse.unquote()`.